# How to locate the button using Selenium

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I tried to find this code

```
<div class="ads-form-bottom__submit">
    <button type="submit" class="ads-form-bottom__publish button button-orange" title="Enviar anúncio"> Enviar anúncio</button>
</div>
```

using the XPath

```
//div[class='ads-form-bottom__submit'][2]/button/following-sibling::div[1]
```

and

```
//div[@class='ads-form-bottom__submit']/following-sibling::button
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a reason to use `following-sibling::`.

Try:

```
//div[contains(@class,'ads-form-bottom__submit')]/button[contains(@class,'ads-form-bottom__publish')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to $(By.id("") alleviates a lot of Xpath issues

Comment: How does By.id help if there are no IDs in the html code?

Comment: it doesnt but it makes troubleshooting easier

Answer (score 0):

To locate the button with text as **Enviar anúncio** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  div.ads-form-bottom__submit>button.ads-form-bottom__publish.button.button-orange[title='Enviar anúncio']
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  //div[@class='ads-form-bottom__submit']/button[@class='ads-form-bottom__publish button button-orange' and @title='Enviar anúncio']
  ```

Answer (score 0):

your both xpaths are incorrect.
first one is missing '@' and in second 'button' is not sibling, rather its a child.

use this

```
    //button[contains(text(), 'Enviar anúncio')]
```